# Request http data that requires password authentication

Tags: python, curl, httprequest

If there's an easier, cleaner way of doing this, please let me know. I'm trying to replicate this call:

`curl -s -u user -k "https://10.10.10.10:8001/h/data/ps4"`

This call requires a password. What I've done to try to mimic this is:

```
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = "https://10.10.10.10:8001"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'user', 'pass')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler, handler)
request = urllib2.Request('https://10.10.10.10:8001/h/data/ps4')
print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as I get:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

The output from the curl command returns a list of strings (e.g., `["a","b","c"]`) -- Ideally I'd like to store this into a python list somehow, but I can't get past the first bit.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes there is. Use the requests lib. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Same as @VincentBeltman Python's HTTP handling is rather low level. You want to use 3rd party modules for most uses.

Comment: "Cleaner" is pretty subjective. I suggest we close this as opinion based. Flagged.

Comment: @DanielAmaya - did you even read the question?

Comment: @MrDuk, yes I did. You're asking for an "easier, cleaner" way of doing it, and what is "easier, cleaner" to one person may not be to another. This question will obviously get a bunch of replies that are opinion based, therefore it should be closed.

Comment: @DanielAmaya - No, you didn't read my question. The question itself has nothing to do with my first statement in the body of the question.. read past the first line before flagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, you can do it like this (from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)):

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

There is a more detailed article on how `requests` can do authentication [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/).

Comment: I appreciate this a bunch - however I'm unsure how to replicate the `-k` parameter in my curl call through this? **edit** sike, found it: `verify=False`

Comment: So, this appears to work, however when I try to `print r.text` it's just blank... however `print r` is equivalent to yours, and `r.status_code` is 200 as well.

Comment: What type of data is returned? You could try `r.content` ([binary data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)) or `r.json()` if it's a [json response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Comment: `r.content` is blank as well - it should just return lists of strings like `["a","b","c"] ["d","e","f"]`

Comment: Nevermind - it appears our service is down and no one noticed. `curl` isn't working either now. Thanks for the help!